# Facebook audience как создать через API

Tags: php, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Пробую как то так, как в документации:

```
 try {
                $custom_audience = new CustomAudience(null, $user->getFacebookAccountId());
        $custom_audience->setData(array(
            CustomAudienceFields::NAME => 'My new CA',
            CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE => CustomAudienceSubtypes::CUSTOM,
            CustomAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION => 'People who bought from my website',
        ));
        $custom_audience->create();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getFile() . ' -- ' . $e->getLine() . ' -- ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

выдаёт ошибку типа

`Object with ID '*********' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.`

Пробую взять уже готовый по id:

```
 $custom_audience = new CustomAudience(6081390900113, $user->getFacebookAccountId());
$custom_audience->read();
$custom_audience->setData(['name' => $custom_audience->getData()['name'] . '2']);
$custom_audience->save();
```

и выдаёт ошибку типа `Application does not have permission for this action`